# get action of submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which is triggered every time a user submits a form on my site.

I want to modify it slightly, so that it checks the action of the submission, and based on the presence of a particular keyword, runs some code.

My code is as follows:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    //do some generic stuff
    var formAction = ""; //get the action of the submitted form

    if (formAction.indexOf('keyword') !== -1) {
        //do some specific stuff for these forms
    }
});
```

How do I get the `action` of the `form` which triggered this call?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    //some stuff...

    //get form action:
    var formAction = $(this).attr("action");

    //some other stuff...
});
```

Comment: Do you need jQuery or something equivalent or does it work out-of-the-box?

Comment: FYI, this won't work for forms whose elements override the action with `formaction` attribute.

Answer (score 21):

if you need Javascript without jQuery:

```
var action=document.getElementById('formId').action
```

with jQuery:

```
var action=$('#formId').attr('action');
```

Answer (score 13):

In JavaScript, you can use getAttribute method:

```
var form = document.getElementById('register_form');
var action = form.getAttribute("action")
```

***Note:*** form.getAttribute("action") is safer than using form.action. Because if you have an input field named "action" within a form, then the browser can return that particular node instead of returning action URL of the form.

[image]

Comment: I think using form.action resulted in an ambiguity because there was an input named "action" in the form.

Answer (score 4):

You can get action attr this way -

```
var formAction = $(this).attr("action");
```

Comment: Do you need jQuery or something equivalent or does it work out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 2):

In *"vanilla"* JS you have the `Element.getAttribute()`
Or (if needed) you could use the `this.action`. See below the slight difference

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents form from submitting
  
  console.log( this.getAttribute("action") );  // "test.php"
  console.log( this.action );                  // <address>/test.php
  
  // this.submit();  // Submit afterwards or use AJAX to construct your request

});
```

```html
<form action="test.php">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [michael-theriot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1758241/michael-theriot) already mentioned, most of the examples here ignore the fact that the submit element on the form could have a `formaction` of its own.

Following code takes this into account, while also working when there is only an action on the form itself too:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e.submitter.formAction) // <address>/test.php
  
  // ...
})
```